# fix replaced quotations in nltk processed text

Tags: python, string, nltk

I'm processing text with NLTK, a light issue I ran into was the following:

```
I am tired of people "quoting me". It's pathetic and annoying!
```

would be turned into:

```
I am tired of people `` quoting me ''. its pathetic and annoying!
```

And I'm pretty sure this happens during the tokenization process.

Now i could easily just use ``` .replace("`` ", "\"") ``` and `.replace(" ''", "\"")` but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: The result gives more information, which can be machine-read quite easily. It gives any code that reads the string a clear indication of where the opening quotes are, and where the closing quotes are. In different environments, different symbols are used for opening and closing quotes, so this information can be very valuable.
Of course, it depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: well at this point im done with processing so im just trying to revert it to its normal format. But if it is so machine-readable then are there any libs that work with this, maybe even a nltk module? i looked but i didnt see anything.

Comment: No, I think what you had (`.replace(...)`) is probably the best you can do to accomplish what you're trying. As an example of code that can read that more easily: this is exactly how TeX and LaTeX quotes work.

Comment: oh, that might be useful with this, thanks a lot!